# Ionic 2 RC2 Cannot hide splash screen

Tags: angular, ionic2

I don't want a splash screen to show at all in my app. I've tried SplashScreen.hide(), removing plugin from config.xml and remove all splash screen preferences, remove directptory splash from iOS/Android in www to no avail :o(

No matter what I do I still get some sort of splash screen grrrrrrr.

How can I remove the splash screen altogether in Ionic 2 RC 2?

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.43
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v7.1.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: Not sure if this makes any difference, but I use Adobe PhoneGap Build to build my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it. You cannot remove the splash screen on iOS! Have made a plain white one that will do the job for now.